# insert attributes dynamically in html elements in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to insert a set of attributes to my a component I want to re use...
now different attributes will come as string to me...
say for example I want to insert an element in my component

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="enter your name"/>
```

then i will get all the attributes as a single string

```
attr = 'type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="enter your name"'
```

in the controller for my component...
and i have to insert that to my conponent  in the html...

i have tried

```
<input {{attr}}/>
```

and

```
<input {{jQuery.parseHtml(attr)}}
```

etc..

but it is not working... also, could not find any solutions...
please share any solutions or some links/references helpful for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input properties to pass data to a nested reusable component. However, AFAIK there isn't an easy way to pass a string of html attributes and apply them automatically. You'd either need to pass them on individual input properties or write code to process the string yourself and map them into attributes for binding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use binding for each attribute you want to change dynamically

Component:

```
typeTxt: string = "text";
maxLengthNum: number = 10;
placeholderString: string ="enter your name";
```

Html:

```
<input [type]="typeTxt" [maxlength]="maxLengthNum" [placeholder]="placeholderString"/>
```

See the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets) to better understand data binding and deal with the different attribute types (Properties, events, two-way, etc.)

---

2. Use the parent tag to dynamically change your template

Component:

```
htmlString: string = '<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="enter your name"/>';
```

Html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Result:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="enter your name"/>
</div>
```